# Possible to catch a hot-reload event in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I'm using `webpack` hot-reload in a `Vue 3`-application.
During development I would like to know when a reload happens in my application itself. The console shows numerous 'reload' texts when it happens, but I need to clear some things in the application when a reload happens.

Any way to catch a hot-reload event?

Comment: See https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ESM build then you can use `import.meta.webpackHot` module injected by Webpack.

```
if (import.meta.webpackHot) {
  import.meta.webpackHot.accept('./module-to-watch.js', () => {
    // Cleanup code
  });
}
```

If you are using IIFE or something else, then you can use `module.hot`:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./module-to-watch.js', () => {
    // Cleanup code
  });
}
```

The './module-to-watch.js' is a path to a module that you intend to watch. It can also accept an array of strings.

Further, if you do not care about the dependencies, then consider using more low level event:

```
if (module.hot) {

  const hotEmitter = require('webpack/hot/emitter');

  hotEmitter.on('webpackHotUpdate', () => {
    // Cleanup code...
  });
}
```

However, this is low-level and not explicitly documented. You can see the example of this in [dev-server implmementation](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/hot/dev-server.js).